# Android periodic sync

Tags: android

I have a `SyncAdapter` that needs to be synced every midnight. I'm executing periodic syncs using `ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync`, but I don't know how to trigger it at midnight.

I've thought on a couple of options but none of them seem quite right:

1. Setup an alarm (with `AlarmManager`) that triggers at midnight, fire a `Broadcast` with a sync intent and register/unregister receivers in every `Activity`.
2. Similar as 1., but using a `Service`. The service is fired on start up and runs indefinitely.

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Comment: Why does it need to be at midnight? Wouldn't that lead to a massive traffic spike all at once?

Comment: The spike can be avoided using a random start for the alarm and triggering it with `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating`.

Comment: And Sync Adapter's do the same thing so why does it need to be at midnight?

Comment: @ianhanniballake The users enter data, which they should upload manually (whenever they're ready). They can forget to do it manually, so the data will be synced once a day. I can't do it while they are working with the data because I could be syncing incomplete work. That's why midnight is a good choice, it's less probable that the data will be synced while they're working on it.

Answer (score 2):

From the Android Sync Adapter guide:

> Notice that addPeriodicSync() doesn't run the sync adapter at a particular time of day. To run your sync adapter at roughly the same time every day, use a repeating alarm as a trigger. Repeating alarms are described in more detail in the reference documentation for AlarmManager. If you use the method setInexactRepeating() to set time-of-day triggers that have some variation, you should still randomize the start time to ensure that sync adapter runs from different devices are staggered.

jlhonora your comment is correct:

> The spike can be avoided using a random start for the alarm and
>   triggering it with AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating

So you are on the right track with the AlarmManager, but should take into account the random start.

See the [Running a Sync Adapter periodically](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunPeriodic) for the full guide I made reference to.